# sqlite-net-pcl nuget missing the API for async sqlite connection

Tags: asynchronous, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, sqlite-net

I am working on a UWP app and I can't find the async API mentioned here.
https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net#asynchronous-api

I have installed only the sqlite-net-pcl 1.5.231 nuget. (https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl)
Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With my tests, there's no problem. I can call the async APIs. Please check if you add the [SQLite.cs](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/master/src/SQLite.cs) and [SQLiteAsync.cs](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/master/src/SQLiteAsync.cs) to your project like the [Source Installation](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net#source-installation) mentioned.

By the way, you could follow the official document [Use a SQLite database in a UWP app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases) to use sqlite database in your UWP app.

Comment: Source files contain errors. It doesn't compile. However nuget works as you mentioned. But it turns out there is an issue with date time format conversion. The old version had this format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" when inserting into DateTime columns but latest nuget it was changed to "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff".

Comment: I found another issue and report in GitHub. https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/issues/840